# NServiceBus: Can it work with NO XML configuration?

Tags: nservicebus

I don't want to use any XML configuration.  Is it possible to have NServiceBus set up with NO XML configuration?  I really want my publisher to be configured all in code, and I want to be able to specify everything from the transport to the serializer to the subscription storate explicitly in code.

Answer (score 5):

yes. [take a look at this gist](http://gist.github.com/574649) which has the code to do exactly this via a custom configuration source. it defaults to using config code if either is not used.

usage would be like such:

```
Configure.With()
    .CustomConfigurationSource(new UserConfigurationSource(
    unicast => {
        // unicast bus setup
    },
    msmq => {
       // msmq setup
    })
 // rest of code
```

Comment: So is UserConfigurationSource a class you hand-rolled yourself?